# The correct structure of questions in the oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query

```
SELECT rep.id,
       rep.VALUE_NUMBER         
FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION rep
where rep.VALUE_NUMBER in 
       ( select o.VALUE_NUMBER 
         from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION 
         where o.key = 'transaction' 
          and  o.parent in 
                     (select i.parent
                      from  IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  i 
                      where i.key = 'reader' 
                      and  i.VALUE_STRING = '4fa11d4e-1819-11ea-80f3-a0369f1c4dcb' 
        ) )
```

When I do this request, I get an answer
[image]

That is, I have different id, as well as VALUE_NUMBER (1575706431704 and 1575700166708) and you can add and query the VALUE_STRING column to have (4fa11d4e-1819-11ea-80f3-a0369f1c4dcb) Like this.[image]

That is, I don't want the answer to be

```
SELECT rep.id,
       rep.VALUE_NUMBER ,
          '4fa11d4e-1819-11ea-80f3-a0369f1c4dcb' as  VALUE_STRING
```

I want this to be the case when I make a request

```
SELECT rep.id,
       rep.VALUE_NUMBER 
FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION rep
where rep.VALUE_NUMBER in 
            ( select o.VALUE_NUMBER
              from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o
              where o.key = 'transaction' 
              and  o.parent in 
                      (select i.parent 
                       from  IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  i 
                       where i.key = 'reader' 
    ) )
```

Each ID has its own i.VALUE_STRING. That is, my question is generalized because it asks me to remove "i.VALUE_STRING" from a subquery?

Comment: Sorry but it's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @APC hi, look, I have a query filtering the fields "where i.key = 'reader' and i.VALUE_STRING = '4fa11d4e-1819-11ea-80f3-a0369f1c4dcb'" I want these fields to be displayed in my answer, this is maybe ??? Something goofy "SELECT rep.id,
        rep.VALUE_NUMBER,
        i.VALUE_STRING "

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi, did you understand what i want to do?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement you want to include the VALUE_STRING for the `reader` records in the projection but you can't get access to it because the `reader` records are buried in a nested subquery.

Here is an alternative way of writing the query which allows access to the  `reader` records. I'm not guaranteeing this is correct, because you haven't posted a complete question with sample input data and required output derived from that sample.

```
with txn as 
       ( select o.VALUE_NUMBER as transaction_value_number
                , i.VALUE_STRING as reader_value_string
         from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o
              join IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  i 
              on  o.parent = i.parent
         where o.key = 'transaction' 
          and  i.key = 'reader' )
SELECT rep.id,
       rep.VALUE_NUMBER,      
       txn.reader_value_string as VALUE_STRING   
FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION rep
     join txn on rep.VALUE_NUMBER = txn.transaction_value_number
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is what I wanted, but you can ask for one more, my original request, here by force https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7db577ac2c0fc98363fcd304dca4b5b0 , but I can't leave it alone your due to lack of experience, I will be grateful for your help

Comment: I tried so https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=938432d5bb2fc7f65cd953d6d272547c, but it didn't work ((

Comment: And another question, when I use your query, I see the answer, and in no column I go, duplicates all fields(4627525 1576563939264
4627525 1576563939264
4627526 1576563939264
4627526 1576563939264
4626608 1576563939264
4626608 1576563939264
)

Comment: As I said, I did not guarantee my solution is correct. If you're getting duplicates, then there's some complexity in the data model which I don't understand because you have posted any data. I'm happy to help out but you need to provide more information.

Comment: I edited the links https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5310d1dd68d3a3e174fffa33a0b24f7c

Comment: thanks for the help but could you comment on what could be duplicated fields in reply ??